# Android SwitchCompat style

Tags: android, switch-statement, styles, switchcompat

I tested my app on my new device with android 5.1.1. In my SettingsActivity i have a switch. I already read some posts and changed it to `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` but the problem still is the following: On my old device the switch looks very nice. you can set two texts for `textOn` and `textOff` and it fits perfectly. but since api 21 or whatever I get this little bastard here:

[image]

It looks like ****. How can I restyle it for all devices like the lollypop switch?

**Edit:**
The question above is answered.
One tiny thing is missing: How to change the color of the text on the switch.(Not the tag on the left side!!!)

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SwitchTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#3F51B5</item>
    </style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/track"
        app:showText="true"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:text="Toggle Switch"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the `layout` and any relevant `style` xmls?

Comment: I think I got it. Have you an idea how to change the color of the switchButton-text?

Comment: I updated my answer, added text color to the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SwitchCompat.setSwitchTextAppearance` you can set the style for the text that appears inside the switch itself.

Add a style something like this and set it using `setSwitchTextAppearance`:

```
<style name="SwitchTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch">
  <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#3F51B5</item>
</style>
```

And you should be able to customize the size, color, etc of your "OFF" text.

Comment: I used your pattern but it seems not to work
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"

Comment: That will not work because `android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"` is not a recognized attribute. You need to use the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace, so it would be like `app:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"`

Comment: Change `android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"` to `app:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"` and it should alter the color and size of the text inside the switch.