# SwitchCompat textColor no response

Tags: android

I'm trying to change color of text set by attribute `textOn` and `textOff`. `textColor` attribute and similat (`textHintColor` etc.) not working. I was trying extend `SwitchCompat` style - but can't find initial style of this element. Should i try to change text in runtime of there is another trick?

Comment: Take a look here:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314877/android-switchcompat-style)
First answer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time